# Check if a url offers a downloadable file?

Tags: php, file, csv, url, file-get-contents

I am currently working on some affiliate feeds where most are offered as raw .csv formats. I am using file_get_contents to generate .csv files along with fputcsv().

Unfortunately there is also a link between my affiliate url's that instantly downloads a csv file when you visit the url in the browser. This needs no further work since it's a perfect .csv file as is.

Since I just put my url's in a array I need to check for when a file is offered as a download link. How can I check for this so I can skip all my default .csv logic and not mess this file up?

I don't know what to search for since I don't know what exactly happens when a file straight up downloads instead of seeing raw csv data. Hopefully somebody can help me out.

Comment: You just want to check if a given link is donwloadable ?

Comment: Sorry for my phrasing but a url can have raw .csv data that is viewable in the browser or a url that you visit can just straight up download a file with your browser right away if you visit it. I need to check for this difference. Edited my title lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a file is downloadable using CURL :

**PHP**

```
    function checkDownloadable($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if(curl_exec($ch) !== FALSE) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks just what I needed, gotta step up my curl game soon.

Comment: Was waiting for the timer :P